# Running node server locally, receive 127.0.0.1 refused to connect error

Tags: node.js

I am running the node server locally on windows 7 enterprise. I receive the following error message: "This site can't be reached 127.0.01 refused to connect". I have scoured google with advice on resetting the default settings, not checking the automatic detect proxy settings etc, but none of them work. The firewall allows chrome, firefox, and IE to access the network.

The strange thing is that I can run xampp locally with no problems, and can access locally built web pages there.

in addition on my previous machine i was able to run pages locally on node with no problem

As always, thanks to you folks for your help.

Comment: maybe permission problem ? Try to run on 8080 for example and see if it's better. Because on linux node can't listen to 80 without root permissions maybe it's the same on windows...

Comment: there is no software called _the node server_, please provide the code you use to start the server on node.js

Comment: var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(request, response){
response.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
response.end('Bey Faka Hao\n');
}).listen(8124);

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8124/');

Comment: figured it out. I was trying to run server.js from the node app (c:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe. It will not work on windows . You need to use windows cmd in the nodejs directory and run it from Administrator:cmd. It works perfectly. Thanks to those who responded.